# Why isn't my loop working?

Tags: ruby, loops

I can't get this program to respond properly to user input. Various looping techniques either only run the block once or run the block infinitely no matter what the user inputs (I've tried `case` and `while` as well). Here's the most recent method I've tried:

```
work_summary = []
begin
  # code that runs a sprint and adds results to the work_summary array
  puts "Would you like to add a sprint, Y/N?"
  sprint = gets.to_s
end until sprint == "N"
print work_summary, "\n"
```

Ruby never objects to my syntax with any of the various methods, but it also never works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
sprint = gets.chomp
```

gets returns string with trailing "\n".

Answer (score 3):

http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#begin

Begin is typically used for exception handling. I think you're looking for a `while` loop.

Here is an example
work_summary = []

```
while true
  puts "Would you like to add a sprint?"
  sprint = gets.chomp
  if sprint == "N"
    break
  elsif sprint == "Y"
    puts "What's your time?"
    time = gets.chomp
    work_summary << time
  else
    puts "I didn't understand your request. Enter Y or N"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks -- I resorted to `begin` when `while` wasn't working, but I'll switch back to `while` now that I know what was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I found two possibility over here which is suitable for you

First one is

```
while true
  puts "Would you like to add a sprint?"
  sprint = gets.chomp
  if sprint == "N"
    break
  elsif sprint == "Y"
    puts "What's your time?"
    time = gets.chomp
    work_summary << time
  else
    puts "Wrong request. Enter Y or N"
  end
end
```

Here Lopp will run until break Doesn't get executed

Second thing you can Modify 1 Line in your code which is

```
sprint = gets.chomp
```

this will extract last special character of your string which is generated by gets and work fine in your case